# SQL Server Express Edition feature and upgrade questions

Tags: sql-server

I want to install and learn T-SQL with SQL Server. The lightest edition that I can find is the 2017 Express edition.

1. Will the Express edition support procedures, triggers, dynamic SQL, PIVOT, sequences, dynamic management views and functions?
2. Will it be upgradable to adding ssis, ssrs and ssas in future (I read documentation on Microsoft community blogs, but couldn't find an answer specific to this edition), maybe I will need them in future.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question and not a specific programming question. The MS website has information about the features available in the various editions of SQL Server.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15). You can always upgrade to a higher edition if you find you need a feature Express does not have.

Comment: Seven times **YES!** to the first question, and **most definitely YES** to the second. The Express edition is a **full-blown version** of SQL Server - it's just limited in its capacity (max 10 GB database size) and processing prowess (max 1 GB of RAM, max 1 CPU) - but it's the ***FULL*** SQL Server as we know it